# UIViewController not present in allocations in Instruments heap shot analysis

Tags: ios, iphone, instruments

I'm using heap stack analysis techniques, as described widely on [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021734/using-heap-shot-analysis-shows-memory-addresses-but-not-lines-of-code-how-do-i)

Everything makes sense, except for I'm trying to track down some UIViewController (subclasses) and they never show up in the allocations list (via parsing it or via search). Since most things in the app's lifecycle are going through VCs, and I can track down other objects allocated in them, I assume there's something I'm missing (...perhaps those are grouped under the much more broad malloc calls?)

I'm trying to track down an over-retained VC, so if anyone can provide useful insight, it'd be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can it perhaps be a Xcode 6 bug?

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages on this yesterday using the simulator, with iOS 8 and Xcode 6.3, with no joy. I think it's not symbolicating properly, hence all the mallocs. I think it's an Xcode bug, as it can't even attach to an iOS 7.1 simulator at all. It was working correctly with an iOS 8 device (8.3). Have you tried on a device yourself?

Have filed radar http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4937802231840768